# how to refactor simple script to be pipeable (take in input from stdout)

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

echo "Phone:" 
read phone
echo
echo "Column:"
read column
echo
echo "New Value:"
read value
echo

index=$(cat $file | grep -n $phone | cut -d: -f1)

cat "$file" | awk -v idx="$index" -v col="$column" -v value="$value" -F ',' '{if (NR==idx) {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (i==col) $i=value; printf("%s%s", $i, (i==NF ? "\n":FS))}} else print}'

echo

exit 0
```

It takes in a file and the user is prompted for a number, column and new value and then updates that particular field. my problem is, I have to call it like so:

```
./update.sh data.csv
```

And I'd like to be able to turn the script into an alias and be able to pipe it using flags instead of prompting the user to enter values, so adding custom flags (-c for column, -v for value and -e for pattern to filter by), something like:

```
cat data.csv | update -c 2 -v "value" -e "pattern"
```

can someone walk me through how I'd transform the script into an alias with flags? (by alias I mean a command, maybe I'm using the alias word incorrectly)

additionally, i'm still learning bash and awk and linux, if you see I'm doing something incorrectly or inefficiently, please correct me.

thanks in advance

p.s. maybe it helps, here's what data.csv looks like:

```
444-555-7777, Max,Weaver, personal:friend:musician
111-222-6665, Craig,Kowalick,office:friend
888-797-2345,Tom, O’Brien, personal:family:musician:midnightsociety
```

Comment: "(by alias I mean a command, maybe I'm using the alias word incorrectly)" ... please just use "command", it's hard to tell what it is you want right now. "turn the script into an alias and be able to pipe it using flags"  I cannot parse that. Do you want to modify the existing script to be able to parse arguments to get the column, value, etc., and read the CSV from input instead, or do you want to have the script be able to do either that or the current way of operating depending on the arguments, or do you want to keep the script untouched and write a wrapper which will work like you want?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i want to be able to rewrite this in whatever way possible so that I can perform the following chain of commands: cat data.csv | update -c 2 -v "value" -e "pattern". Currently I have to type: ./update.sh data.csv and then answer a given prompt, I want to chain my custom command to a previous command that outputted a CSV file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getopts](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopts.1p.html) to parse the arguments and then `awk` or similar to match CSV fields, e.g. (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts ":p:c:v:e:" arg; do
    case $arg in
        p) phone=$OPTARG ;;
        c) col=$OPTARG ;;
        v) val=$OPTARG ;;
        e) ere=$OPTARG ;;
        *) printf 'Unknown argument "%s"\n' "$arg" >&2
           exit 1
           ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

then use awk do do whatever you want with the CSV e.g. (again untested and just an example, not intended to do whatever it is you really want to do with the above variables just showing how to use them):

```
awk -v phone="$phone" -v col="$col" -v val="$val" -v ere="$ere" '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    ($1 == phone) && ($0 ~ ere) && ($col == val) {
        print "Matched: " $0
    }
' "${@:--}"
```

That `"${@:--}"` tells awk to read from file name(s) if any were passed in or read stdin otherwise.

You'll probably want to add some code in the shell script or in the awk script to verify any mandatory variables are populated before using them in the awk script as I show above. You could add shell code like this between the getopts loop and the call to awk:

```
while [[ -z "$phone" ]]; do
    echo "Phone:" 
    read -r phone
done
```

to ensure the variables are populated by prompt+response if they weren't already set from the command line.

I've assumed above that by "pattern" in your question you want to do a full-line extended regexp match which is why I've named the associated variable `ere` instead of `pat` or similar. I know it's counter-intuitive but don't use the word "pattern" when stating your requirements or writing code for pattern matching. It's highly ambiguous, like going to a car dealership and only telling the salesman you want to buy a "vehicle". Be specific about what kind of pattern you want to match in what context(s), see [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern).

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for! can you explain shift $((OPTIND-1))? and yes by pattern I meant grep -E [pattern]

Comment: `shift $((OPTIND-1))` removes from `"$@"` all the arguments+options already parsed above it by `getopts` so from then on `"$@"` is just the list of file names, if any, passed to the script.

Comment: ah okay, without which "${@:--}" wouldnt work im assuming