# running awk on stdin not working

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to run an awk command based on whether or not a file was given as an argument and, if not, just run it on stdin like so:

```
 38 for index in "${line_numbers[@]}"; do
 39    if [ -n "$file" ]; then
 40       echo "hi"
 41       cat "$file" | awk -v idx="$index" -v col="$column" -v value="$value" -F ',' '{if (idx==NR) {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {    if (i==col) $i=value; printf("%s%s", $i, (i==NF ? "\n":FS))}}}'
 42    else
 43       echo "bye"
 44       awk -v col="$column" -v idx="$index" -v value="$value" -F ',' '{if (idx==NR) {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (i==col) $i    =value; printf("%s%d%s", $i, i, (i==NF ? "\n":FS))}}}'
 45    fi
 46 done
```

the file is read in using getopts (but this isn't important as I'm relying on stdin for the following but I thought I'd mention this code):

```
  3 file=""
  4 unset -v number column value  
  5 cmd="echo"
  6 
  7 while getopts f:n:c:v: opt; do
  8    case $opt in
  9       f) file="$OPTARG";;
 10       n) number="$OPTARG";;
 11       c) column="$OPTARG";;
 12       v) value="$OPTARG";;
 13       *) printf>&2 '%s\n' "Usage: $0 [-f file] [-n number] [-c column] [-v value]";;
 14    esac
 15 done
```

But the output of the for loop is just "bye" followed by "bye" (it runs twice which is expected based on the data), but the awk command isn't run at all.

I was under the impression that stdin is the default that commands use, but the awk command isn't running anything even though it should output something as I've tested it.

Any idea why the awk command in the `else` block isn't running?

The command I'm running is:

```
cat data.csv | ./update.sh -n 444 -c 2 -v " Alex"
```

and the data is:

```
444-555-7777, Max,Weaver, personal:friend:musician
111-222-6665, Craig,Kowalick,office:friend
888-797-2345,Tom, O’Brien, personal:family:musician:midnightsociety
444433443,fgdfg,gdfg,fdgdfgf:test:test:test2
```

so the output should be:

```
444-555-7777, Alex,Weaver, personal:friend:musician
444433443, Alex,gdfg,fdgdfgf:test:test:test2
```

Edit: apparently something is consuming stdin, and while I can't enter debug mode (vim is telling me it doesn't recognize :set -x), here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_stdin=$(cat)

file=""
unset -v number column value  
cmd="echo"

while getopts f:n:c:v: opt; do
    case $opt in
        f) file="$OPTARG";;
        n) number="$OPTARG";;
        c) column="$OPTARG";;
        v) value="$OPTARG";;
        *) printf>&2 '%s\n' "Usage: $0 [-f file] [-n number] [-c column] [-v value]";;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ "$column" -gt 4 ] || [ "$column" -lt 1 ]; then
       echo "this script can only handle cols1-4. for group editing, try ./groups.sh"
       exit 1
fi       

declare -a line_numbers

grep_output=$(grep -n "$number" <<< "$my_stdin" | cut -d: -f1)

if [ -n "$file" ]; then
    grep_output="$(cat "$file" | grep -n "$number" | cut -d: -f1)"
fi

echo "$grep_output"

IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra line_numbers <<< "$grep_output"

for index in "${line_numbers[@]}"; do
    if [ -n "$file" ]; then
        echo "hi"
        cat "$file" | awk -v idx="$index" -v col="$column" -v value="$value" -F ',' '{if (idx==NR) {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (i==col) $i=value; printf("%s%s", $i, (i==NF ? "\n":FS))}}}' "${@:--}"
    else
        awk -v col="$column" -v idx="$index" -v value="$value" -F ',' '{if (idx==NR) {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (i==col) $i=value; printf("%s%s", $i, (i==NF ? "\n":FS))}}}' <<< "$my_stdin"
    fi
done

echo

exit 0
```

Comment: Launch the script interactively and try to input the data yourself (copy paste). Maybe something else is consuming stdin? Enable debug mode to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: out of curiosity, is this consuming stdin?  30 IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra line_numbers <<< "$grep_output"

Comment: I don't think so, it redirects a string, why would it consume stdin? Try with debug mode to see what exactly is happening (`set -x`)

Comment: Hard to debug with lines 16-37 missing. However, you can re-read `cat "$file"` as many times as you want, but there is only one stdin -- it won't start over, so the whole logic is flawed when it is inside a loop. You seem to be running awk for every element in `line_numbers`: you should store those in an awk array, and have it read the input once (whether it is `${file}` or `stdin`).

Comment: yeah sorry about that, I included the entire script if you guys wouldnt mind taking a quick look

Comment: Definitely, like @Paul_Pedant said, there is one `stdin`, so anyways you should probably save `stdin` to a variable and use that as much as you want. In a loop a single `awk` will consume all of `stdin`.

Comment: What is `grep_output="$(grep -n "$number" | cut -d: -f1)"` doing? You aren't giving any input to `grep`, what is it supposed to search through? And why is your output `bye`? That doesn't appear in your script.

Comment: I showed how to run an awk command on a file if provided or stdin otherwise in [my previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/759355/133219) - why can't you just do what I did in that answer?

Comment: `grep` in `grep_output="$(grep -n "$number" | cut -d: -f1)"` is consuming stdin.

Comment: Running grep to find line numbers and then looping on them calling awk to do something at that line number is a very inefficient and fragile approach. Don't do that. If you post a question with concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry @EdMorton not trying to undermine anyone, just misunderstanding a lot atm.

Comment: undermining never came to mind, I'm just trying to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Can you please explain what the script is supposed to do? You have chosen a very complicated way (which is normal of course, we all do this when learning) so it is really hard to guess what your end goal is. Why is `Max,Weaver` becoming Alex in your output? Please explain what the script is supposed to do in words.

Comment: ah okay understood, I've updated my code with the "${@:--}" you provided in your previous answer, the file isn't being read in tho

Comment: you removed the `shift` after the getopts loop from my previous command.

Comment: the script is supposed to allow a user to change a field for specific phone numbers. they provide the number and column and replace all occurrences at the specified column with the new value

Comment: OK but that's what my previous answer lets you do, why not just use it?

Comment: Sorry, I added the shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))! the script is completely updated and the command I'm running is: ./update.sh -f data.csv -n 444 -c 2 -v "Alex" but there is no output

Comment: FWIW most Unix commands that operate on a file don't have a `-f` or similar option to specify the file name, that just comes after all of the options, i.e. the more Unix-y interface would be `./update.sh -n 444 -c 2 -v "Alex" data.csv` rather than `./update.sh -f data.csv -n 444 -c 2 -v "Alex"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line consumes your stdin:

```
grep_output="$(grep -n "b" )"
```

So by the time you get to the `awk` bit, there is nothing left to consume. I can't figure out what your script is supposed to do, since the output you give doesn't seem to come from the input, but a simple way of making awk work on a file if present or stdin if not is to use a variable:

```
awk 'awk command here' "$file"
```

To illustrate, consider this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '{ print $1 }' "$1"
```

If you run it with an argument, `$1` will be set and `awk` will try to read it:

```
$ echo "foo" > file.txt
$ foo.sh file.txt
foo
```

If you run it without an argument, it reads from STDIN:

```
$ cat file.txt | foo.sh
foo
```

---

Now, I *think* what you want to do is to change the value of the column given on any lines starting with the number given. If so, you could simplify your whole script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts f:n:c:v: opt; do
    case $opt in
        f) file="$OPTARG";;
        n) number="$OPTARG";;
        c) column="$OPTARG";;
        v) value="$OPTARG";;
        *)
          printf>&2 '%s\n' "Usage: $0 [-f file] [-n number] [-c column] [-v value]"
          ;;
    esac
done


## You probably want to set up the same set of checks for the other required fields
if [ -z "$column" ]; then
  echo "Please specify a column number with -c." >&2
  exit 1
elif [[ ! "$column" =~ ^[0-9][0-9]*$ ]]; then
  echo "Column value '$column' is invalid. Please use a number from 1 to 4." >&2
  exit 1
elif [ "$column" -gt 4 ] || [ "$column" -lt 1 ]; then
       echo "this script can only handle cols1-4. for group editing, try ./groups.sh" >&2
       exit 1
fi       

## The trick here is setting num to ^$number so we can
## then use it as a regex matching the beginning of the line
awk -v num="^$number" -v col="$column" -v value="$value" -F ',' \
    'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{ if ($0 ~ num) { $col=value; print }}' "$file"
```

You can now run this as needed:

```
$ cat data.csv | foo.sh -n 444 -c 2 -v " Alex"
444-555-7777, Alex,Weaver, personal:friend:musician
444433443, Alex,gdfg,fdgdfgf:test:test:test2

$ foo.sh -n 444 -c 2 -v " Alex" -f data.csv 
444-555-7777, Alex,Weaver, personal:friend:musician
444433443, Alex,gdfg,fdgdfgf:test:test:test2
```

Note that your `grep` would match `444` anywhere in the file. If that is what you want, use `num="$number"` instead of `num="^$number"`.

Comment: so in my case, it should be "$2"? because -f is "$1"?

Comment: @Mathew see updated answer.

Comment: amazing! can you explain what the carrot means in num="^$number"?

Comment: @Mathew In regular expressions, `^` means "match the beginning of the line". Since all your examples had the number at the beginning, I was guessing this is what you wanted. If you instead want to match the number anywhere at all on the line, remove the `^` as explained in the final Note.

Comment: and just to check my understanding, this works because nothing else is consuming stdin? if there is a file, it'll use it, otherwise itll use stdin. what if I needed to use stdin multiple times? would i store it in a variable as mentioned above? because @Ed Morton recommended against it

Comment: Ah okay understood, I thought it was awk specific

Comment: @Mathew yes it works because nothing is consuming stdin. As for how to do it if you need to, the usual answer is that you do not and should not need to. Reading things twice is inefficient so there are almost always better ways of doing whatever you need to do.

Comment: makes sense, UNIX philosophy if im not mistaken, reading from stdin twice would mean doing more than one thing, which isn't the way to go

Comment: TIL, though that's not  something POSIX specifies it looks like indeed all modern awk implementations (at least the one I tried: gawk, mawk, onetrueawk, busybox) ignore empty arguments so `awk 'awk code' ''` behaves the same `awk 'awk code'`. How peculiar! That's not the case with the oawk and nawk from the heirloom toolchest though, oawk complaining it can't open files with an empty name, and nawk skipping those empty  arguments but otherwise  not reading stdin.